# Converting files to Avid-friendly DNxHD MXF

Tags: ffmpeg, avid

*Please forgive the noob question, I'm new here. I've looked for an answer on this forum but not found one so far. I've also tried the BMXlib forum.*

I'm trying to convert small video files that have been digitally generated as **DNxHD QuickTime MOV's** (via FFmpeg, and not sourced from a camera) **into DNxHD MXF files** that I can import into Avid Media Composer using the Media Tool. I'm on MC 8.3.1.

These are video-only files, there's no audio.

I'm using FFmpeg to generate a raw **.dnx file**:

```bash
ffmpeg -i [input-file] -vcodec dnxhd -f rawvideo -b:v 185M -flags +ildct -y [intermediate-file]
```

and then using **raw2bmx** to wrap that as an MXF:

```bash
raw2bmx -t avid -o [output-file-prefix] -f 25 --vc3_1080p_1238 [intermediate-file]
```

There are no errors that I can see in the resultant outputs. The resultant file is an MXF file which the Media Tool will recognise. The file size seems right (just a few K more than the original file). The duration and video format are correctly recognised, so it appears to be fine.

However, when I try to play back the clip, it won't play. In the source window I get a long and apparently incomplete error message:

```bash
HagridBase: Err: 0 | -1979514218 | lk_interruptobject.cpp | 1152 | Error Code: kLPKerr_CodecFatalDecodeError Msg: "Card2:Decode:Pip1DecodeError", Err: 0 | -1979514218 | lk_interruptobject.cpp | 1157 | Error Code: kLPKerr_CodecFatalDecodeError Msg: "Ca
```

Has anyone got any suggestions where I might be going wrong? I'm new to BMX so I may be making a simple mistake.

---

#### Console Output

```
When using FFmpeg to convert from the MOV to the raw .dnx, this is the console output:
~~~
Reached BMX.B.
secondParameters:
-i "C:\Users\animator\Documents\Renumbers\900-0002_stage1_GHRs.mov" -vcodec dnxhd -f rawvideo -b:v 185M -flags +ildct -y "C:\Users\animator\Documents\Renumbers\900-0002_stage2_GHRs.dnx"
ffmpeg version N-70520-g9d7e42e Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 12.100 /  5. 12.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\animator\Documents\Renumbers\900-0002_stage1_GHRs.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 183502 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p(tv), 1920x1080, 183500 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 dnxhd
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'C:\Users\animator\Documents\Renumbers\900-0002_stage2_GHRs.dnx':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dnxhd, yuv422p, 1920x1080, q=2-1024, 185000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 dnxhd
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dnxhd (native) -> dnxhd (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   47 fps=0.0 q=1.0 size=   42112kB time=00:00:01.88 bitrate=183500.8kbits/s    
frame=   96 fps= 94 q=1.0 size=   86016kB time=00:00:03.84 bitrate=183500.8kbits/s    
frame=  130 fps= 86 q=1.0 size=  116480kB time=00:00:05.20 bitrate=183500.8kbits/s    
frame=  180 fps= 89 q=1.0 size=  161280kB time=00:00:07.20 bitrate=183500.8kbits/s    
frame=  229 fps= 90 q=1.0 size=  205184kB time=00:00:09.16 bitrate=183500.8kbits/s    
frame=  250 fps= 91 q=1.0 Lsize=  224000kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=183500.8kbits/s    
video:224000kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
~~~

When I run raw2bmx, I'm not seeing any console output so I can't see anything to paste.

Running FFprobe on the resulting MXF file gives this information:
~~~
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=dnxhd
codec_long_name=VC3/DNxHD
profile=unknown
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/25
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=1920
height=1080
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv422p
level=-99
color_range=N/A
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=unspecified
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=25/1
avg_frame_rate=25/1
time_base=1/25
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=250
duration=10.000000
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:file_package_umid=0x060A2B340101010101010F00130000005580237EF2BE012E060E2B347F7F2A80
[/STREAM]
~~~
```

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

I can provide more of the console output or possibly a couple of example files if it would help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please do provide the console output from all the operations. There may well be clues in them.

Answer (score 2):

*In the end I have discovered what the problem was here, to an extent, and thanks to a post on the BMXlib forum:*

By changing the option in raw2bmx from `--vc3_1080p_1238` to simply `--vc3`, this forced raw2bmx to look at the data to determine what video format it was - and it turns out that in this case, **it wasn't vc3_1080p_1238**.